# Каким образом можно передать perl скрипту xml через stdin?

Tags: xml, perl, ввод

Каким образом можно передать perl скрипту xml через stdin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В простейшем случае вот так:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

while (<>) {
    print ;
}
```

Ну и тест:

```
cat xml.xml | ./script.pl
```

или так:

```
./script.pl < xml.xml
```